# hidden footer gradually appears on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this effect on a project

http://www.cera-groupecera.com/en/

like this page the footer is hidden and appears as you scroll.
The page is wrapped in a page-content element and the footer is fixed to the bottom z-indexed 0
what happens is as you reach the end of the window the page -content margin rises as you scroll.
I can't really find a way to do it with j query

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,you just position it on the bottom of the page or in any other place you want it to stay,to hide it you can use z-index=-1;

```
//<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h2><code>fixed</code></h2>
<div class="fixed"><div class="expand"></div></div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

CSS

```
@import "compass/css3";

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 48px;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 32px auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 // overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fixed {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/600/200/animals');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.expand {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cu01m218/

Answer (score 0):

I did one example for you.

```js
$(function(){
  
  calcFooter();
  
function calcFooter () {
  var footer = $('.footer').height();
  var mainContent = $('.main-content');
  
  mainContent.css('margin-bottom', footer);
}

$(window).resize(calcFooter);
  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;  
 }
 
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;

  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="main-content" style="margin-bottom: 200px;">
    <h1>This is main content.</h1>
    <p>Scroll down to reveal footer!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    <p>This footer.</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this element which appears at the bottom is footer tag.
In this case it will be something like this:
html:

```
<footer></footer>
```

in your css:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Then you have to add a class which will make footer appear

```
.active {

display: block;

}
```

and your jquery will be something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        if (!$(footer).hasClass('active')) {
            $(footer).addClass('active');
        }
    } else {
        if ($(footer).hasClass('active')) {
            $(footer).removeClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```